# Dryer Vent Covered

Tags: dryer

I live in a second floor condo with a neighboring unit underneath.  Their dryer was vented through the roof...I could visibly see the vent from my upstairs window.  Last year the entire building had a new roof installed and the vent is now gone (roofed over). Would this cause moisture in my upstairs unit?  I am definitely having some moisture problems, mildew smell, etc.

Comment: Since you are on the second floor, do you have access to the attic?

Comment: Find out whether they relocated the dryer vent through an outside wall or out the soffit.

Answer (score 2):

If the dryer is venting in to the attic space, then absolutely this could cause moisture buildup in the attic. You need to get your condo board to address this right now before the problem becomes even more expensive.

Comment: And it also would be a fire hazard due to lint buildup!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the code, but doesn’t sound acceptable by any means.  I think there are some dryer “vents” systems that vent into some reservoir that you will empty but I doubt local/building codes will permit it and I don’t think it is permitted for gas dryers.

Bottom line - I think you need to vent outside somehow - hammer drilling and 6”-8” hole in a wall is not a fun day imo.  Roofers shouldn’t have closed a vent - what were they thinking.

Answer (score 2):

All air removed by mechanical vents shall be exhausted to the exterior and shall not be exhausted to the attic, crawl space or ridge vents. (See ICC Code M1501.1.)

I’d notify the building manager and let them know you’re going to notify the local Building Official.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you'll experience moisture buildup in your living space if the vent is in the attic, and not in a wall or other interior cavity. The humidity in the attic could cause mold and eventually rot, but the ceiling materials and insulation (if present) should adequately prevent significant moisture transfer to your rooms.